# How can I divide this ipv6 address use to sscanf in c?

Tags: c, parsing, ip-address, ipv6, scanf

For example , I want to separate this address.

```
http://[1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001/index.html

like..

    protocol = http
    address = 1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f
    port = 8001
    path = index.html
```

So I used this sscanf code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void main()
{
//    char url[128] = "http://10.1.35.1:8088/inedex.htm";
    char url[128] = "http://[1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001/index.html";
    char url_6[128], port[10], path[40];

    char *tok, *cp, *host, *proto, /**port, *path,*/ *tok6;
    char *hostbuf, *portbuf, *buf;
    int c, len, ulen, cnt_6 = 0;
    struct in6_addr result;

    ulen = strlen(url);
    len = ulen *2 + 10 + 3;

    if(strncmp(url, "http://[", 8) == 0)
    {
        tok = &url[8];
        tok[-4] = '\0';
        proto = url;
        sscanf(tok, "%2000[^]]:%s", url_6, path);

        if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, url_6, &result))
        {
            printf("successful ipv6 address\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid ipv6 address\n");
        }
        printf("path= %s\n", path);
        printf("tok = %s\n", tok);
    }
}
```

But I don't understand this line.

```
sscanf(tok, "%2000[^]]:%s", url_6, path); //this line is okay.
```

Actually, it's the first time, I'm writing this line.

```
//port and path is pointer.... *port, *path...
sscanf(tok, "%2000[^]]:%10[^/]%s", url_6, port, path);
```

but when I debug this line, then segmentation fault accurs.... 
What did I do wrong ?
please answer this question.

thanks.

Comment: Did you consider [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)?

Comment: of course. but.. this sscanf isbetter than strtok to this parsing.. i think . do you have better idea on this?

Comment: Don't do [`void main()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did wrong is twofold:

1. You specify maximum widths to `sscnaf` which are larger than your buffers.
2. You don't tell `sscanf` to consume your delimiters after you reach them (`]` and `/`).

So a somewhat fixed version (with your clutter removed, and `main` made standard conforming):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char url[128] = "http://[1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001/index.html";
    char url_6[128], port[10], path[40];

    char *tok;

    if(strncmp(url, "http://[", 8) == 0)
    {
        tok = &url[8];
        tok[-4] = '\0';
        //sscanf(tok, "%2000[^]]:%s", url_6, path);
        sscanf(tok, "%127[^]]]:%9[^/]/%39s", url_6, port, path);
        //                   ^^      ^- delim '/' consumed here
        //                   |+- delim ':' consumed here
        //                   +- delim ']' consumed here

        printf("path= %s\n", path);
        printf("port= %s\n", port);
        printf("url_6 = %s\n", url_6);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](http://ideone.com/32Sbwu).

Comment: @kara, please stop editing my post to add elements irrelevent to the question you asked. This isn't the place to showcase your program, it answers how to get rid of the segmentation fault.

Comment: OMG! Sorry i didnt know that.

Comment: @kara, no worries. You seem to be fairly new to SO. So have a quick read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Thanks to helping me ! ^^!